# How to update values(likes, numComments) dynamically in a multiuser React Native/ Relay app?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, relayjs

I want to synchronize RelayStore with remote database. I am building a react native app with relay that has posts showing the number of likes and number of comments much like facebook. However, such data is fetched once and stored in cache. If person X fetches the post when numLikes is N and person Y likes this post later, X wont see the update in likes to N+1 till Relay Store doesn't update its cache which I am not sure how to trigger.

How do I go about solving this? Is there an efficient way to somehow use subscriptions/ WebSockets etc? Should I use forceFetch everytime the component becomes visible? Is this the best way to solve this?